# Where did i go wrong in if-statement php?

Tags: php, if-statement

Need little help, always get the last value 188490?

```
if(isset($_POST['zapremina']) and is_numeric($_POST['zapremina']))
        {   
if ($_POST['zapremina']<=1050)
$_POST['zapremina']=1030;
if (($_POST['zapremina']>=1151) and ($_POST['zapremina']<=1300));
$_POST['zapremina']=2010;
if (($_POST['zapremina'] >= 1301) and ($_POST['zapremina'] <= 1600));
$_POST['zapremina']=4400;
if (($_POST['zapremina'] >= 1601) and ($_POST['zapremina'] <= 2000));
$_POST['zapremina']=9110;
if (($_POST['zapremina'] >= 2001) and ($_POST['zapremina'] <= 2500));
$_POST['zapremina']=45000;
if (($_POST['zapremina'] >= 2501) and ($_POST['zapremina'] <= 3000));
$_POST['zapremina']=91200;
if ($_POST['zapremina'] > 3001);
$_POST['zapremina']=188490;
        }
else
$_POST['zapremina']=0;
```

I think is a little mistake, does anybody knows, txanks a log

Comment: $_POST['zapremina'] is bigger than 3001.

Comment: also remove the `;`'s in if statements.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you need to do `else if`.

```
if ($_POST['zapremina']<=1050)
    $_POST['zapremina']=1030;
else if (($_POST['zapremina']>=1151) and ($_POST['zapremina']<=1300))
    $_POST['zapremina']=2010;
else if (($_POST['zapremina'] >= 1301) and ($_POST['zapremina'] <= 1600))
    $_POST['zapremina']=4400;
```

etc.

As to why: You're checking against your variable and then you set it to another value, which tends to be higher than anything you're checking against AFTER you assign it.

So anything that's higher than would produce 188490 in the end.

The else means: Stop comparing at the first match.

Furthermore you need to remove the `;` after the if statements, because the `;` means: `End of operation`. In this context it would mean `End of If`...that in turn means, that the following line will ALWAYS be executed, the value of your variable doesn't even matter at that point any more.

Answer (score 0):

remove ; [semicolon] at the end of every if statements and used else if ladder in current scenario

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['zapremina']) and is_numeric($_POST['zapremina']))
        {   
if ($_POST['zapremina']<=1050)
$zapremina=1030;
if (($_POST['zapremina']>=1151) and ($_POST['zapremina']<=1300))
$zapremina=2010;
if (($_POST['zapremina'] >= 1301) and ($_POST['zapremina'] <= 1600))
$zapremina=4400;
if (($_POST['zapremina'] >= 1601) and ($_POST['zapremina'] <= 2000))
$zapremina=9110;
if (($_POST['zapremina'] >= 2001) and ($_POST['zapremina'] <= 2500))
$zapremina=45000;
if (($_POST['zapremina'] >= 2501) and ($_POST['zapremina'] <= 3000))
$zapremina=91200;
if ($_POST['zapremina'] > 3001)
$zapremina=188490;
        }
else
$zapremina=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two errors:
1) You have semicolons (;) after almost every if-statement line of code. This way these statements don't even affect anything and your POST-variable is set six times.
2) You set your POST-variable to new (higher) values and check afterwards with this new and higher value which is not what you try to accomplish I guess.

Also - as datasage already said - avoid writing to the POST-variable.